# How to update multiple objects in loopback?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, loopbackjs, update-attributes

can somebody help me to update some multiple object in
loopback but i don't have any idea on how to do it..

this is what i tried...

```
Bond.ParseBondQoutesheet = (data, cb) => { //eslint-disable-line
    //// now update multiple
    for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i = +i) {
        const filter = {
            where: { id: data[i].id },
        };
        Bond.findOne(filter, (err, newdata) => {
            if (!err) {
                newdata.updateAttributes(data[i], function (err, updated) {
                    if (!err) {
                        if (data.length === i) {
                            console.log('updated success')
                            cb(null, updated);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('err')
                        console.log(err)
                        cb(err, null);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                cb(err, null);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run that but because of JavaScript's async nature it will behave unexpectedly
what you can do in order to solve this would be to  loop it using recursive method like this

```
Bond.ParseBondQoutesheet = (data, cb) => { //eslint-disable-line
    //// now update multiple
    let data = data;
    updateAllSync(0);
    function updateAllSync(i) {
        if (i < data.length) {
            const filter = {
                where: { id: data[i].id },
            };

            Bond.findOne(filter, (err, newdata) => {
                if (!err) {
                    newdata.updateAttributes(data[i], function (err, updated) {
                        if (!err) {
                            if (data.length === i) {
                                console.log('updated success')
                                updateAllSync(i+1);
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('err')
                            console.log(err)
                            cb(err, null);
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    cb(err, null);
                }
            });
        }else{
            cb(null,i); // finished updating all docs sync
        }
    }
    };
```

Comment: you need to make this process run Synchronously  other wise it wil behave unexpectedly.. use this code I have provided and you should be fine..

Comment: wow great thanks!, but is this the correcy way of updating multiple objects in loopback? sorry i'm newbie here..

Comment: well since you need to do this sync way this is the way to do it.  because this process need to run one ofter another. there is a method called updateMany() but that's just another story considering your case.  if you find this answer was helpful, please mark it as the answer

Comment: you can read about it in here but you can't use it in here. because of your execution needs retrieve data from the db and update it . When using  updateMany()  
 - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany
it will only update all the documents matching the same criteria